# Where can I find more information about JavaScript terms?

Tags: javascript, terminology

I have started to learn JavaScript on Codecademy recently and I was wondering where I could find more information about it. I am really confused with some of the terms that are being used like "elements" , "passing something through a function" , etc. Is there a website I could go to that would explain the terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably best to just ask whatever specific questions you have here.

An `element` is typically a DOM element which is a reference to a particular object in the web page such as a button, a div, a textarea, etc...  You use the element reference to get or set properties on the DOM element, call methods on it or register callbacks for event handling.

"Passing something through a function" sounds to me like "passing something into a function" which would refer to passing an argument to a function as in:

```
draw("rect", 0, 0, 100, 50);
```

Where the five items in the parentheses are the arguments passed into the function.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just grab the O'Reilly reference book and read up on all the basics including some stuff you won't understand right off the bat (that's okay - just keep exposing yourself to it occasionally).

Passing is something you do with arguments or parameters as in, stuff you pass into a function. Elements can be DOM stuff, but it's also a common word for the memory locations assigned to array indexes. e.g. The first 'element' of the array is a `myArray[0]`

Online, I don't recommend W3Schools for learning more advanced JS stuff but it's not a bad reference when you forget details of common JS stuff and there's not many places you can go to find all of the basics in one spot like that.

The mozilla developer's network MDN is probably more detailed and has better/more up-to-date/complete info typically but it's a little more chaotic in terms of organization.

Answer (score 0):

You should first Google the term thoroughly in search of definitions and/or explanations. If you can find nothing, feel free to ask it on here. Here are your terms defined:

**Elements:** I'm assuming that when you're saying "elements," you're talking about array elements. Basically, these are the individual values which an array consists of. Here is an array consisting of three elements:

```
var arr = ["array element 1", "array element 2", "array element3"];
```

To access an array element, you can use `arr[i]`, with `i` being the index of the element. Note that arrays are zero-indexed:

```
arr[1]; // return "array element 2"
```

**Passing something through a function:** The term you're looking for, I believe, are arguments. Arguments are values passed to functions. The following function takes three arguments: `val1`, `val2`, and `val3`.

```
function logValues(val1, val2, val3) {
    console.log(val1 + val2 + val3);
}
```

You specify the arguments a function can receive within the parantheses after the function name. To call the function with the arguments provided, you include the comma-separated arguments inside the calling line. For example:

```
logValues("bob", " ", "the plumber"); // logs "bob the plumber"
```